# Kendo Grid data disappears on navigation button click

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have got a Kendo grid that displays data with paging functionality enabled.

Clicking on the page number buttons changes the page with data however on clicking on the navigation buttons (next, previous, first, last) the grid gets empty with no records available message.

The snippet below is my grid code:

```
function BindTranscript(ObjectData) {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                noRecords: true,
                dataSource: {
                    data: ObjectData,
                    pageSize: 20,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Heading: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                date: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                person: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                Visitor: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                Category: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                details: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                // height: 550,
                // groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataBound: resizeGrid,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [{
                    template: "<div class='icon'>" +
                    "<span class='k-icon k-i-data'></span></div> #: heading #",
                    field: "heading",
                    title: "heading",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "date",
                    title: "Date"
                },
                {
                    field: "person",
                    title: "person"
                },
                {
                    field: "Visitor",
                    title: "Visitor"
                },
                {
                    template: "<div class='category other'>" +
                    "<div class='cat-name'>#: Category #</div></div>",
                    field: "Category",
                    title: "Category"
                },
                {
                    field: "details",
                    title: "details"
                }],
            });
        }
```

[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk9nz.png)

[Data Grid With Page Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeAY5.png)

Code Snippet for resizeGrid function:

```
function resizeGrid() {
            var gridElement = $("#datagrid"),
                dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content"),
                gridHeight = gridElement.innerHeight(),
                otherElements = gridElement.children().not(".k-grid-content"),
                otherElementsHeight = 0;
            otherElements.each(function () {
                otherElementsHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            });
            dataArea.height(gridHeight - otherElementsHeight);
        }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console window?

Comment: No , no error thats why i had to post this at stackover flow. the grid gets populated perfectly fine everything works perfect (even the page number buttons) except the navigation buttons.

Comment: Do you have a print screen or a runnable example (Dojo) to replicate the issue?

Comment: You have something called resizeGrid on dataBound.  What is in that?  That databound function is going to run when you click the navigation buttons.  Seems to me whatever resizeGrid is doing is your problem.  But you didn't share that code so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Sandman i have added screenshots as you have suggested. 
Rani i have tried removing that function but still the problem still remains. I have added the code in my initial question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I need to destroy the grid before rebinding it that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your `schema.model.fields` and `column` `fields` incorrectly (based on the single object example you attached to your question).

Definition should be like:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            noRecords: true,
            dataSource: {
                data: ObjectData,
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            //Heading: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            date: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Agent: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Visitor: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Category: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Notes: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            // height: 550,
            // groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,                
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "date",
                title: "Date"
            },
            {
                field: "Agent",
                title: "person"
            },
            {
                field: "Visitor",
                title: "Visitor"
            },
            {
                template: "<div class='category other'>" +
                "<div class='cat-name'>#: Category #</div></div>",
                field: "Category",
                title: "Category"
            },
            {
                field: "details",
                title: "details"
            }],
        });
```

Note: I removed `Heading` as I don't know which property it belongs to (if any).

Also knocked together a small [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IFume/2) aswell.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help i found out i need to destroy the grid before rebinding it that was causing the issue